# Facelet tag parameter not recognized by PrimeFaces p:ajax

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, glassfish-3

I have a simple Facelet tag:

```
<ui:composition>
  <ui:insert />
</ui:composition>
```

which is used in order to avoid declaring multiple `c:set` tags.
Let's say I registered it in the facelets taglib library with the name `view`, and use it like this:

```
<my:view bean="#{myController}">
  <p:inputText value="#{bean.value}>
    <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" listener="#{bean.handleValueChanged}" />
  </p:inputText>
</my:view>
```

The attribute `value` is perfectly resolved by `p:inputText`, but `p:ajax` throws this:

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:153)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:237)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:47)
```

Is it a bug or expected behavior?

**Update**:
I just tried the same with f:ajax and it worked!

Btw, the environment is as follows:
Glassfish 3.1.2
PF 3.0, 3.2, 3.3

**Update2**:
[This](https://community.jboss.org/thread/164032?tstart=0) issue with `RichFaces` is absolutely identical. Seems to be like a PrimeFaces bug (I'll post an issue on PF bug tracker today).

Comment: As promised, I opened the issue on PF bug tracker: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My colleague has just provided a patch to resolve this issue.

The current implementation of `AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl#processAjaxBehaviour` is as follows:

```
public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

        try{
            listener.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{});
        } catch (MethodNotFoundException mnfe) {
            MethodExpression argListener = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
                        createMethodExpression(elContext, listener.getExpressionString(), null, new Class[]{event.getClass()});

            argListener.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{event});
        }
    }
```

He proposes to tweak it like this:

```
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext;
```

---

```
public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

        try{
            listener.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{});
        } catch (MethodNotFoundException mnfe) {
            FaceletContext fc = (FaceletContext) context.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
            MethodExpression argListener = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
                        createMethodExpression(fc, listener.getExpressionString(), null, new Class[]{ event.getClass() });

            argListener.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{ event });
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this will be approved by PF team.

Comment: Nice job! This can theoretically solve a problem which we have when using `<p:ajax event="rowEdit">` in a tag file.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! Though, all kudos should go to my colleague (I doubt if he has SO account). I just noticed the problem, and he solved it :)  Is there an open bug regarding `<p:ajax event="rowEdit/>` or a question on SO? Just curious, because I haven't come across this issue, so I want to take a look.

Comment: No, it's for my job. We've a tag file which contains a `<p:column><p:rowEditor>` along with a `<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.save}">` so that it can be included as a single tag by `<my:rowEditorColumn>` in data table. However the `<p:ajax>` did never invoke the listener method.

Comment: How can this fix the problem since the original exception is a PropertyNotFoundException and not a MethodNotFoundException?

Answer (score -1):

The tweak does not work with my use case which is more complex than a single ui:include.

```xml
<c:forEach items="#{items}" var="item">
            <ui:include src="#{item.uri}">
                <ui:param name="itemBean" value="#{item.bean}"/>
            </ui:include>

</c:forEach>
```

I think the listener's variable mapper must be reused inside the new MethodExpression

Comment: mention it in comments or ask another question please. SO is not a forum.

Comment: I just cannot, not enough reputation and asking a new question is not a solution. By the way, I have submit a patch to this issue http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4075 (as nithril) which was accepted and applied

Comment: sorry about the reputation limit. This problem still exists in current 3.5 did your problems disappear after this fix?

Comment: The problem dissapear as soon as the action method takes an argument of AjaxBehaviorEvent type instead of the PF event. It is complex to fix completely the issue so I think it is an acceptable workaround