# How to pass bean action/listener method via <ui:param> of <ui:include>

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, facelets, managed-bean, uiinclude

I'm using `<ui:include>` to load a data table (I'm using Primefaces). I want use `<ui:param>` in the `listener` into the tag `<p:ajax>`. I tested the code that is down, but not trigger the event **onRowEdit** or **onRowCancel**. 
This is my page:

```
...
<ui:include src="../Componentes/tablaEditable.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="columnas" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.dataTableColumns}" />
     <ui:param name="bean" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.listTabla2FuenteDTO}" />
     <ui:param name="aceptarEdicion" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowEdit}" />
     <ui:param name="cancelarEdicion" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowCancel}" />
</ui:include>
...
```

My data table:

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form >
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean}"  scrollable="true"  scrollHeight="100" var="dato" editable="true">
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{aceptarEdicion}"  />
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{cancelarEdicion}"  />
        <c:forEach items="#{columnas}" var="column" varStatus="loop">
            <p:column headerText="#{column.header}" sortBy="#{dato[column.property]}">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{dato[column.property]}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{dato[column.property]}" style="width:100%"  />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>     
            </p:column>
        </c:forEach> 
        <p:column style="width:32px">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "tabla2FuentesHL7")
@ViewScoped
enter code herepublic class Tabla2FuentesHL7 {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<DataTableColumn> dataTableColumns = new ArrayList<DataTableColumn>();
private List<Tabla2FuenteDTO> listTabla2FuenteDTO = new ArrayList<Tabla2FuenteDTO>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    listTabla2FuenteDTO = Test.getFuenteTabla2();
    dataTableColumns = CargarTablas.getTabla2FuenteHL7();

}

public List<Tabla2FuenteDTO> getListTabla2FuenteDTO() {
    return listTabla2FuenteDTO;
}

public List<DataTableColumn> getDataTableColumns() {
    return dataTableColumns;
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Elemento modificado");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Modificación cancelada");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

}

This is the error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /Componentes/tablaEditable.xhtml @12,76 listener="#{cancelarEdicion}": /Modulos/hl7.xhtml @31,104 value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowCancel}": The class 'com.queres.xedoc.consola.componentes.Tabla2FuentesHL7' does not have the property 'onRowCancel'.
```

If I change this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{aceptarEdicion}"  />
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{cancelarEdicion}"  />
```

for this:

```
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowEdit}"  />
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowCancel}"  />
```

my code works fine, but I need a dynamic data table. Is there any way to pass a parameter to the listener?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<ui:param>` can only pass value expressions, not method expressions.

Better make use of the ability of EL to parameterize method names via brace `[]` notation. Then you can just declare the method names as plain vanilla `String`.

```
<ui:include src="../Componentes/tablaEditable.xhtml">
     ...
     <ui:param name="beanEdicion" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7}" />
     <ui:param name="aceptarEdicion" value="onRowEdit" />
     <ui:param name="cancelarEdicion" value="onRowCancel" />
</ui:include>
```

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{beanEdicion[aceptarEdicion]()}"  />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{beanEdicion[cancelarEdicion]()}"  />
```

---

**Update** as per the comments, it appears to still not work in PrimeFaces  5.1 even though the [related issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4075) says that it's already fixed in 3.5. You'd basically need to reopen the issue.

In the meanwhile, you can workaround this with help of [`<o:methodParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/methodParam) tag of JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org). This basically converts a value expression to a method expression:

```
<ui:include src="../Componentes/tablaEditable.xhtml">
         ...
     <ui:param name="aceptarEdicion" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowEdit}" />
     <ui:param name="cancelarEdicion" value="#{tabla2FuentesHL7.onRowCancel}" />
</ui:include>
```

```
<o:methodParam name="aceptarEdicionParam" value="#{aceptarEdicion}" />
<o:methodParam name="cancelarEdicionParam" value="#{cancelarEdicion}" />
...
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{aceptarEdicionParam}"  />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{cancelarEdicionParam}"  />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not able to make it work. Now I have this error:  `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'beanEdicion' resolved to null`

Comment: Which PF version? This is a known issue in `<p:ajax>` and should already be fixed in 5.x. See also related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691636/facelet-tag-parameter-not-recognized-by-primefaces-pajax

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.1.11  and Primefaces 5.1. Thanks again :)

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.11 is rather old (almost 3 years already!). Can you try 2.1.29? That should bring a lot of bug fixes and performance improvements along.

Comment: I upgraded my JSF version  and still the same error. Anyway , thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 2.2 . Could have something to do with the problem ?

Comment: @BalusC: Did you reset your reputation or was it an overflow ;-)

Comment: GlassFish 2.2? Did you doublecheck the version number? Isn't it 3.1.2.2?

Comment: @BalusC: I tried with Glassfish Server 4.0, and the error is the same. Any idea? Thanks for  all

Comment: Awkward, it appears that this is not properly fixed in PrimeFaces side as indicated by recent comments on [issue 4075](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4075). Do you use the utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), or are you open to using it? It offers a `<o:methodParam>` which would be the alternative solution. It basically converts a value expression supplied via `<ui:param>` or tag attribute to a true method expression.

Comment: @BalusC If I can keep using Primefaces and his data table,  I would have no problem with OmniFaces. I'll try. Thanks :)

Comment: It's an utility library, offering helper components, tags, functions and classes. It works fine together with PrimeFaces.

Comment: @BalusC I used OmniFaces and it worked well . Thank you very much ! I will upload the code with the solution.